# MongoDb create unique index on a field not in all documents

Tags: mongodb

I added a new field in the production Mongo Database and need to create a unique index on it. If I try to create one it keeps throwing 'exception: E11000 duplicate key error index:'.

I understand documents without the new field have a `null` value which is causing the uniqueness violation. How should I do it?

Comment: You need to make sure all documents have the new field with unique values. That means you would need to update all of them.

Comment: @Khang, was afraid of that approach but seems that is the only solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Sparse Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) which contain only entries for documents that have the indexed field. Example:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "newIndex": 1 }, { sparse: true } )
```

Comment: > If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or later, partial indexes should be preferred over sparse indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraint) so that unique constraint apply only to documents where the field is present. E.g

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { newField: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { newField: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

Comment: still getting the same error: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: db.trips.$reservationId_-1  dup key: { : null }'

Comment: so you have documents where the field exists and is explicitly `null`. adjust the `partialFilterExpression` condition to meet your data.

Comment: @rishabh agarwal answer worked. Here is the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

Comment: @Kihats, of course it does. The page you are referring to has an important yellow box. It worth reading.